# storing char pointers inside a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, char

On rare occasions my program crashes and i don't know why.
I think it might be related to how i store char pointers inside a vector.

```
vector<char*> vec;

// here i store text for later
void pushToVector(const char *text) {
  char *t = new char[strlen(text)+1];
  strcpy(t, text);
  vec.push_back(t);
}

// now i want to print the first element and then erase it
void print() {
  if (vec.size() < 1) return;
  printf("print: %s", vec.front());
  char *t = vec.front();
  vec.erase(vec.begin(), vec.begin()+1);
  delete[] t;
}
```

will this always work? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are using `std::vector`, why not use `std::string`? It makes this much simpler.

Comment: Is there any need to use manually new/delete and storing to vector and char*? Why not c++? What about vector<string>? And if you want really char* why not smart pointers?

Comment: yes i will probably switch to std::string, but i am still wondering if the code above always works or will it crash on rare occasions?

Comment: There is nothing really wrong with your code, but it is more or less C-style and it can be broken simply by modifying something later. C++ is about objects and ownership. It is always good to see in the code who owns which memory. Therefore you should at minimum use smart pointers for your memory. Manually new/delete is a no go in your use case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems to be ok, although it is rather risky code. These are the unsafe points I see:

- You do not check if the parameter `text` is really a null-terminated string
- Working with pure pointers
- No clear ownership of the string object on the heap (I wouldn't expect a `print` function to delete something)

Unless you are bound to C-style strings I would strongly recommend to use `std::string`.

Comment: Agree, the code as posted does not _in itself_ contain crashiness, but it does promote the possibility, and it may be impossible to fully answer the OP's question without a [MCVE] (i.e. seeing how the functions are used).